# Can't edit answers in Firefox 31.5.0

Tags: bug, firefox

I'm unable to edit answers with 31.5.0. The edit link exists and can be clicked, but then the whole answer simply vanishes. Not edit box, nothing.

**Update:** Regarding [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161), the latest two versions of the browsers are supported. In Firefox, the latest two maintained (stable) versions are 31.5.0 and 36.0.1, so I believe my browser version isn't too old.

Comment: The current version is 36.0.1, time to update perhaps.

Comment: Stack Exchange only supports the most recent versions of modern browsers; 31 is no longer 'recent'.

Comment: See [Which browsers are officially supported? And what else do I need?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161)

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: I just updated my question to make clear why I don't believe my version is too old.

Comment: @vog: right, it's up to the developers to decide if they want to support Firefox ESR releases. They have not done so in the past.