# Different types of quotes in answers

Tags: feature-request, markdown

At present, in a Stack Overflow answer, it is possible to indicate that some content is a quote by prefixing each line with `>`. A stylesheet then gives it visual formatting to distinguish it.

From time to time, I find myself answering a question and quoting both:

- Sections of the original question (when it is a little complex and best dealt with in smaller parts).
- External resources (such as specifications) which support the answer

For example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417923/html-meta-tag-for-content-language/4417940#4417940).

It would be useful to be able to distinguish between the two. Possibly by prefixing the quote with a comment (in the style of the code block syntax highlight language selector) leading to a class being added on the quote.

Comment: I use things like italics and quote characters for this purpose.

Comment: For some reason nobody cares for this kind of suggestions. Some time ago I proposed the distinct markup for the **error messages** (for which there is no satisfying markup at all), but it was trampled over in the comments and of course was never ever considered by the folks in charge.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: Feel free to link your post if you want (its certainly more useful than vague references and it sounds like it could have relevant discussion since it sounds very similar). And I'm not quite sure what you mean by people trampling over it but if people disagreed with the premise then that is the will of the people(TM). Opinions differ and it sounds like you were in a minority on this one. Move on and stop worrying about it.

Comment: @Chris Here you are, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339075/a-special-markup-for-error-messages

Answer (score 24):

I have never a need to distinguish between those. If you are confused, then that's the problem with how answer is written, not with some missing style.

You can use hyperlinks or caption to clearly identify source:

---

OP said:

> Blablabla

But [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/default.aspx) only stated:

> bla

---

There are more options to format text, if you really up to mixing many quotes (as a dialogue?), then just give them some *style* (mixing it, using as header, etc.)

> Style 1, play text

> *Style 2, italic*

> **Style 3, bold, probably bad idea**

> <kbd>Style 4, I am button, shall we build a [castle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1974/299295)?</kbd>

> Style 5, spoiler!

> <sub><sup>Style 6, small</sup></sub>

> <sub><sup><sub><sup>Style 7, even smaller</sup></sub></sup></sub>

Comment: Consider changing the castle link [directly to the castle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1974)?

Comment: You could possibly even use the small text at the start/end of the quote separated by a new line to say where it came from.

Comment: Umm.. how can I see the actual way to use this if I can't simulate an edit to see the syntax?

Comment: @GrayCygnus, can't simulate? Simply click [edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/345673/edit) under the post to see how format is achieved.

Comment: Exactly, I cant edit this post to see how you wrote this

Comment: @GrayCygnus, you should be able to edit answers, [click here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/345673/edit) . If you can't - that's your problem (e.g. [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288005/1997232) is one), can you be more informative: what happens after you click link in either of my comments?

Comment: Sorry, was on mobile and could not provide more details. When I click edit a red pop-up appears saying: `Suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta sites.` Most probably as I am still below the 2k edit privilege.

Comment: Seems that this edit restriction is on every meta sites BUT Meta SE, where I have actually simulated edits to answers to get the value from them. I asked a Meta SE [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301529/unable-to-get-value-from-answer-due-to-restricted-edit) regarding this problem, in case anyone is interested.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that many readers of your answers will be random visitors that came in through a search engine and are not part of the community. They won't know about any site-specific formatting rules that distinguish one thing from another.

Is there a widely recognized standard style / markup to distinguish those two kinds of quotes?

If so, you should probably note that in your request.

If there is no standard way to graphically distinguish the two types of quotes, prefixing each section with a header explaining the quote's origin as per @Sinatr's answer might be easier to understand to outsiders.

Answer (score 1):

That's a very good idea, and could be neatly implemented, asking you for the source link while you press a button having some text selected, thus making a quote from the external source. I am sure it won't make enormous load for the SE employees to implement. Or they can even make it crowdsourced, as I am sure there are designers who'll willingly supply that tiny bit of code and design required for this feature.

But there is a strange phenomenon about Meta. No matter what you suggest, even if it will do no harm at all, there are always people to say "I don't see any problem here. Just tinker here and there, surely you can cough up a plausible solution from the tools available" or "nobody ever needs it" or "there is a greasymonkey script that you can adopt".

Some time ago I posted [a similar suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339075/a-special-markup-for-error-messages), which is extremely useful, but it was trampled over as usual. I dunno what makes people fiercely oppose any new feature.

Comment: All features start at -100 points, you know. Everything costs time to design, time to implement, time to debug, time to document, time to maintain.

Comment: I can understand this reasoning from SO employees. Of course the new header is much more important. But I don't understand SO participants voluntarily refusing any improvement that could make their experience better and also dramatically improve the overall site efficiency.

Comment: *"I dunno what makes people to fiercely oppose any new feature."*  - You are over-generalizing.

Answer (score 1):

I love quoting the relevant bits from a long question myself. Only occasionally I have found the need to quote both from the question and an external resource, but I have faced the same problem. I usually went with italic text for one source and normal roman for the other ([exhibit A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31091772/javascript-es6-computational-time-complexity-of-collections), [exhibit B](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24080786/1048572)).

I would really like to see a new kind of markup for citing external resources. It might render similar to a default `<blockquote>`, but with a different left border. In markdown, I'd propose the use of the vertical bar (pipe, `|`) - for example:

```
This is a [common usenet practice](https://www.netmeister.org/news/learn2quote4.html):

| Every now and then you may wish to quote not only from the article you are responding to,
| but also give examples from books for example. […]
| If you have a long quote, it is common to indent the text or you can use another
| quotationmark. To differentiate between the quotationmarks, it is common to use "|"
| (vertical bar).
```